# How to increment and use a value in Jquery and Razor pages, in ASP.net core 2.0

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-core-2.0, razor-pages

I have this script here, but i need to either be able to use Jquerys ival, or be able to increment the model pages ival from the jquery loop. Think a typcal c# for loop.

The different examples:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("button").click(function () {
        $(".divs").each(function (index, element) {

            var ival = 0;
            $(element).css({
                top: @Model.Positions.GetValue(ival, 0),
                left: @Model.Positions.GetValue(ival, 1)
            });

        });
    });
});
```

(ival isnt recognized since they are technically in different scopes, one in model and one in jquery)

And:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("button").click(function () {
        $(".divs").each(function (index, element) {

            @{
                int ival = 0;
            }
            $(element).css({
                top: @Model.Positions.GetValue(ival, 0),
                left: @Model.Positions.GetValue(ival, 1)
            });
            @{
                ival++;
            }
        });
    });
});
```

(Thought that would work but it doesnt ^)

Comment: By the time javascript/jquery runs, all the razor processing has completed (razor is server-side, js is client-side).

Comment: What's creating the `.divs` ?  Does your razor know how many they'll be? or are they generated by jquery after the page has loaded?

Comment: Good to know! It doesnt solve my problem but atleast i know how it works , and to think of that when moving forward.

Comment: The .divs are premade by html code at the moment, but the model does in theory know how many there are.

Comment: Looks like you want to store div positions and then move them around, Your best be would be to convert the `Model.Positions` to a javascript variable at the start and then use them from there as required.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense @freedomn-m , How would i go about converting it to a javascript variable? Tried just doing var name = @ Model.Positions but that doesnt seem to work. Do i need to use something other than the 2d array i am using now?

Comment: They key is to deserialise your Model into a json object that javascript understands.  The accepted answer shows how to do this as well as recommending you move away from "arrays" and use proper object collections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try to reproduce your problem with two different solutions. I assume you have a class which will be used in order to store your values:

```
public class Position
{
    public int top { get; set; }
    public int left { get; set; }
}
```

You will have a property in your PageModel which will store a list of Positions and you will load a list of values to this list

```
public class TestModel : PageModel
{
    public List<Position> Positions { get; set; }

    public void OnGet()
    {
        Positions = new List<Position>
        {
            new Position {left = 10, top = 20},
            new Position {left = 20, top = 30},
            new Position {left = 30, top = 40},
        };
    }
}
```

Now you have two options. The first option is to generate your dives with C# code and the second is to generate a json object which will be used with javascript.

**First Solution**

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Positions)
{
    <div style="left: @(item.top)px; top: @(item.top)px">
        contents of your div
    </div>
}
```

**Second Solution**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var data = @Html.Raw(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.Positions));
</script>
```

This will generate the following code in your razor page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var data = [{"top":20,"left":10},{"top":30,"left":20},{"top":40,"left":30}];
</script>
```

Now you can use the data object in order to set the top and left using javascript.

I hope it helps.

Comment: This is what i was looking for! But it does break some of my other code (Anchors connecting divs togheter). Either way, it's the correct answer, thank you!